# What is difference between SharePoint REST and ODATA?

Tags: rest, wcf, odata

I have read that SharePoint REST and ODATA provide web services like WCF to fetch list/items, etc.

1. So what is difference between REST and ODATA?
2. Please provide a **programmatic example** to show the difference. For example: how we can use REST and how we can use ODATA, say to fetch list items.? Or is there no programmatic way to differentiate as ODATA is used to implement REST? Just guessing!
3. Is it correct to say that ODATA/REST now replaces the web services and WCF concept? So, we no longer need to create web service with Server object model and expose it to other applications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2458407

Answer (score 0):

" As Franci said, OData is based on Atom Pub. However, they have layered some functionality on top and unfortunately have ignored some of the REST constraints in the process.

The querying capability of an OData service requires you to construct URIs based on information that is not available, or linked to in the response. It is what REST people call out-of-band information and introduces hidden coupling between the client and server.

The other coupling that is introduced is through the use of EDMX metadata to define the properties contained in the entry content. This metadata can be discovered at a fixed endpoint called $metadata. Again, the client needs to know this in advance, it cannot be discovered.

Unfortunately, Microsoft did not see fit to create media types to describe these key pieces of data, so any OData client has to make a bunch of assumptions about the service that it is talking to and the data it is receiving."
Link: http://www.bizcoder.com/2009/11/30/oh-data/

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458407/difference-between-odata-and-rest-web-services

Another Good Article i saw, check this one
http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/NancyB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=b6efd474-248a-4b16-ab88-afdb6fa31b65&ID=25

Comment: The reason why I posted the link you reference as a comment on the question is because I'm not sure if it is really really SharePoint related, and perhaps a duplicate from SO (if that is even possible to tag here)

Comment: The original poster of this answer has added that this answer is extremely outdated due to way newer versions of OData.

Comment: I think something as simple as _The difference is that OData is a specific protocol; REST is architecture style and design pattern._ should suffice

Comment: guys, can you check the updated question and answer please.